# Best javascript console for chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firebug

i been using firebug in firefox, which is great tool for debugging code for php/javascript. recently some stuff stop working on my site, well works fine in firefox, but does not in chrome, so i need to debug it in chrome, but i cant find any good debugger for it, do you guys have any suggestion on this.

Comment: Do you realize there's one built in?  Under Tools->developer tools?  I like it even better than firebug...

Comment: There is a free firebug extension for Chrome in thir webstore? Search firebug at http://chrome.google.com/webstore. I still like the default debugger better, however.

Comment: from Google to call JS console - Use the keyboard shortcut Command - Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux)

Comment: Here you get lambda expressions for JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Examples

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The chrome developer tools/webkit.  On my mac cmd+option+i opens it up.  Its got everything you need: a profiler, a console, resources, a debugger, etc....

You can open it up manually in the "tools" part of this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As hvgotcodes has already pointed out, the best way would be to  use the chrome's integrated inspector (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> if you're on windows). If you're too keen on firebug, there is a [firebug-lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) extension for other browsers (such as chrome). It's not as powerful at it's older brother (firefox's firebug), but it can get the job done.